# Is it possible to install a Windows device driver using Wine?

Tags: drivers, windows, wine, compatibility

I have a Windows 7 64-bit driver for a device that I would like to use with my system. If it was possible to load it with Wine and put that command correctly in my .bashrc, I would be good to go.

Comment: Jeez Louise man - whachu thinkin? usin' Wine at that point? Not one of my better ideas. But the Wine question stands.

Comment: No, not possible, never was, never will be. Wine does not and cannot have that level of access to hardware. There was in the past a tool - ndiswrapper - designed to use some very specific Windows WiFi drivers for some very old devices that had no other way. Even this was always a "hack" with far from perfect results. Perhaps better to ask about support for the actual hardware instead of wasting time with what you think is a solution - it isn't - or posting non-answers. While at that it'll be great if, again instead of wasting time, you also answer to the requests of your previous question.

Comment: What device? Please be specific. There's most likely a linux driver for your device. If there isn't one in the kernel, there's probably a module you can compile from source.

Comment: @mchid Probably this device: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379778/is-there-a-linux-driver-anywhere-and-in-any-stage-of-development-for-an-airlink1

Comment: Drivers are actually *kernel modules*; wine or windows emulation is way down the software stack (with the kernel at the closest to your actual CPU or hardware) so your question to me makes no sense.  Do you understand OSes, software stacks etc..  you're asking for a near user-level layer of software to operate like a near-hardware level part of the software stack.

Answer (score 4):

In general it's not possible to install Windows device drivers in Ubuntu including via Wine. Emulators can be used to simulate hardware that is different from the host machine, but as its initials indicate **W**ine **I**s **N**ot an **E**mulator.

If you search the internet maybe you can find a Linux driver for your device or ideally a driver for your device that is packaged as a .deb file for easy installation on Debian-based operating systems. Install the Linux driver for your device if there is one available, otherwise if your device is not compatible with Linux you're out of luck.