# creative super xifi gamer headphones

Tags: sound, headphones, soundcard

can use creative superXifi gamer headphones with kubuntu ?
if yes how to install software on kubuntu ?

Comment: The SXFI Control software is for Windows and Mac only. Other than that of course you can use it. The software is only for RBG lights and equalization, something you probably can control via the mobile apps as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install a Windows device driver using Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379795/is-it-possible-to-install-a-windows-device-driver-using-wine)