# How to install an RTL8852BE driver that will work on Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

I installed the latest Ubuntu(23.10) version on a usb drive and tried booting it. The wifi driver is not found. My device has a RTL8852BE driver.

How to use a wrapper to make a windows supported driver work on Linux?
How to install a a new driver that will work?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to install a Windows device driver using Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1379795/is-it-possible-to-install-a-windows-device-driver-using-wine)